# Xamarin__HttpClient__HttpResponseMessage-Content --- Getting HTML instead of JSON

Tags: post, xamarin, xamarin.forms, httpclient, httpresponsemessage

```cs
HttpClient myClient = new HttpClient();
myClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);
```

Base address already specified on client it's URL.

```cs
var encodedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Obj);
myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage response = await myClient.PostAsync("test.php/yourAPI",new StringContent(encodedObject, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
  var responseContent =  response.ToString();
  var responsebody = response.Content.ToString();
  Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
  string responseBodyAsText = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

Comment: Are you in control of the server side code as well?

Comment: In away Yes ! it's not a Public server ! to answer your question

Comment: In a lot of these cases the server is throwing an error and defaulting to the error page (html). the endpoint you are calling. Is it a web api or normal Asp.Net MVC

Comment: I have tested the API with POSTMAN and it's working fine, still it's not the case with Xamarin. Additionnaly "response" get a response code 200 OK but the content is NO JSON it's HTML.

I am using a Web API

Comment: Try clearing the headers before adding default

Comment: You are probably going to have to show some more details about your setup to get a better assessment of the problem. check how to provide a [mcve]

Comment: You say it works with post man. inspect the request being sent by portman and then inspect/compare the request being sent by your code.

Comment: for more details, it's all my code, I just removed the URL

Comment: thats not all the code. its a snippet. you say the client is created and that base address is added. that is not in the code you showed in the example. Show a complete example so that the code can be used to replicate your problem. At this point others will have to guess what you have before the code you have displayed. you can always replace the url with a fake one.

Comment: that's all i implemented so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Method PostAsync has as first argument the complete URI of The API. Therefore, it should be like follow :

```
    HttpResponseMessage response = await myClient.PostAsync("http://bla-bla-bla/test.php/test",new StringContent(encodedObject, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

And there is no need to define the BaseAddress.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a content negotiation issue. Try clearing the `Accept` header before adding the json media type

```cs
myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
//...other code removed for brevity.
```

this code sets the Accept header to "application/json", which tells the server to send data in JSON format.

Reference source: [Calling a Web API From a .NET Client in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

Comment: Already Tried it. Same issue. HTML content instead of JSON Content